# Show the onboarding screen to first time user in ember

Tags: facebook, ember.js, ember-simple-auth

I have a fb login integrated in my ember app.I have used ember-simple-auth to implement this.I am facing problem for the first time user.I have to show some onboarding screen to the first time user.For this my server is sending a sign_up flag as false for the first time user when he log in and when he finishes all the onboarding screen I will make an api call to server to make it true.From next time onwards if user log in again the sign_up is true and I should move him directly to feed screen rather than showing him the onboarding screen.

I am not sure how to do this.Is there any good article about it?.Please share some code how to do it.Thanks in advance.You will be life saver.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `computed property` in your `controller` which observes `sign_up` flag like this.

```
isSignedUp: Ember.computed('sign_up', function(){
    return this.get('sign_up');
})
```

Now in your template, you can have your onboard screen with conditional rendering like this:

```
{{#if isSignedUp}}
    <h1>You are signed in</h1>
{{else}}
    <h1>This will be the place to put your onboard screen</h1>
{{/if}}
```

Note: you can also directly use `sign_up` flag in your template for conditional rendering. I have used a computed property just to show you.
Hope it helps.